# Ru python script via BAT script

Tags: python, batch-file

Good afternoon,

The following code executes as expected on my personal computer, but doesn't on my work computer despite the same Python version being installed.
To test, all I am trying to do is run a simple python script print("hello")
My BAT file opens python in the command prompt and opens windows store, but the python code is not displayed.
Experts, please help!

```
python
"C:\\Users\\ShaneN\\Python\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe"
  "C:\\Users\\ShaneN\\Desktop\\testing.py"

     Pause
```

[image]

Comment: Batch file basics. You have extra line breaks and you have python.exe twice.

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for the reply. I removed python from the beginning and removed the breaks and boom, it worked.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
python C:\Users\ShaneN\Desktop\testing.py
pause
```

You do not need to call the python path explicitly. I guess it since you calling python explicitly it expects you to do something within python ;)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It still doesn't open the python script but opens windows store and  the command prompt..

Comment: Then simple try: python C:\Users\ShaneN\Desktop\testing.py

Answer (score 0):

This worked :)

```
"C:\\Users\\ShaneN\\Python\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe" 
 "C:\\Users\\ShaneN\\Desktop\\testing.py"

 pause
```